# Angular costum comparator getting object key

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, comparator

i am creating a rather complex directive that creates a table with both frontend pagination and searching.

Now since you should only be able to search on specific fields in the data array i will need to create a custom comparator.

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in dataArray | filter:search:costumComparator"> </tr>
```

And in my link function:

```
scope.customComparator = function (field,input) {
}
```

Problem is that i am unable to see which field in `data` i am currently inspecting.

The goal of this assignmen is to compare the field key with shown fieldkeys in the table and only allow the user to search on keys that are actually shown.

I have one part of the assignment done which is an array that displays the keys of fields that i am showing.

However i cant use this for anything untill i know which fieldkey i am currently looking at in my `customComparator`.

So my question is:

Is there a way i can get the field key inside my `costumComparator` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can set dataArray object then it will work.

```
$scope.dataArray  = {};
```